# Power Query -- Group-by-Result Expand

Tags: powerbi, pattern-matching, grouping, powerquery

Here's an example of my existing data set. I have unique parts (Part) grouped by what factory # (Factory) they're used in and when the parts started to be used in operation (Part Install Year).

| Part | Factory | Part Install Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2018 |
| 2 | 100 | 2018 |
| 3 | 100 | 2018 |
| 3 | 200 | 2019 |
| 3 | 300 | 2020 |
| 4 | 400 | 2019 |
| 5 | 400 | 2020 |
| 6 | 500 | 2018 |

Desired Output is below. I need to group all the related parts by the lowest numbered factory they are installed in (Part Grouping) and then calculate the earliest year any part was installed in that factory (Factory Install Year). I'm having trouble figuring out how to create the Factory Install Year. Thank you!

| Part | Factory | Part Install Year | Part Grouping | Factory Install Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2018 | 100 | min of all Dates in Factory 100 |
| 2 | 100 | 2018 | 100 | min of all Dates in Factory 100 |
| 3 | 100 | 2018 | 100 | min of all Dates in Factory 100 |
| 3 | 200 | 2019 | 100 | min of all Dates in Factory 100 |
| 3 | 300 | 2020 | 100 | min of all Dates in Factory 100 |
| 4 | 400 | 2019 | 400 | min of all Dates in Factory 400 |
| 5 | 400 | 2020 | 400 | min of all Dates in Factory 400 |
| 6 | 500 | 2018 | 500 | 2018 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Part Install Year", type number}, {"Factory", type number}}),
EarliestYear = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Factory"}, {{"EarliestYear", each List.Min([Part Install Year]), type nullable number}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(  #"Changed Type", {"Part"}, {
    {"data", each _, type table },
    {"MinFactory", each List.Min([Factory])},
    {"EarliestYear", each try EarliestYear[EarliestYear]{List.PositionOf(EarliestYear[Factory],List.Min([Factory]))} otherwise null}
}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Factory", "Part Install Year"}, {"Factory", "Part Install Year"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]